# Smarty foreach to json javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, smarty, google-tag-manager

I am trying to build google dynamic remarketing for online store and I have problem with many product id's in cart.

Here is my code:

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ids = "{/literal}{foreach from=$products|json_decode key=pId item=p name=i}{$p.id_product}{if not $smarty.foreach.i.last}, {/if}{/foreach}{literal}";
  var total = "{/literal}{displayPrice price=$total_products_wt}{literal}";
  total = total.replace(/[zł]/g, "");
  total = total.replace(/[,]/g, ".");
            dataLayer.push({
                'event': 'fireRemarketingTag',
                'google_tag_params': {
                    'ecomm_prodid': ids,
                    'ecomm_pagetype': 'cart',
                    'ecomm_totalvalue': total
                }
            });
        </script>

 {/literal}
```

Still getting error from google tag assistant - "Multiple product IDs need to be stored in an array."

it looks like this

```
ecomm_prodid:367\, 74, ecomm_pagetype:cart, ecomm_totalvalue:109.80
"ecomm_prodid": "367,
      74",
```

it should look like this;

```
ecomm_prodid:367,74, ecomm_pagetype:cart, ecomm_totalvalue:109.80
"ecomm_prodid":       [
        367,
        74
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you need to do, is to change the `"` characters around the `var ids` definition to `[` and `]`, like this:

```
var ids = [{/literal}{foreach from=$products|json_decode key=pId item=p name=i}{$p.id_product}{if not $smarty.foreach.i.last}, {/if}{/foreach}{literal}];
```